# How can I get the value of ActivatedRoute in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have two pages that require authentication, so I've created an `AuthGuard` that will redirect to a login form when an un-authenticated user hits that route. This is working perfectly, however, I would like to set it up so that the user is redirected to the page they were initially trying to access.

I've added `data` to my route, so that I can pass a `page` parameter, and then redirect to the appropriate page after login. This is not working, as I can not get the contents of `data`; most attempts have resulted in an error. What I have below does not error, however it doesn't work either as `data` comes back empty `{}`

### app-routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'map',
        loadChildren: './map/map.module#MapPageModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
            page: 'map'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'collections',
        loadChildren: './collections/collections.module#CollectionsPageModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
            page: 'collections'
        }
    },
];
```

#### login.page.ts

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

login(formData: any) {
    ...

    if(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.page === 'map') {
        this.router.navigate(['/map']);
    }

    ...
}
```

When I log the following I get `undefined`

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.page);
```

How can I get the contents of `data` so I can see the page value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

`data` was not being passed to the `login.page.ts`, however it **was** being passed to `auth.guard.ts`, so all I had to do was capture it there and send it as a `queryParam` to `login.page.ts`

#### auth.guard.ts

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    ...
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: route.data });
    ...
}
```

#### login.page.ts

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

page: any;

constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((res) => {
        this.page = res.page;
    });
}

login(formData: any) {
    if (this.page === 'map') {
        this.router.navigate(['/map']);
    }
}
```